# Usage of multiple Validation rules in Firebase Database

Tags: json, database, validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unclear on a couple of aspects of Firebase Database validation rules, and have already [read the documentation a couple of times](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#validate) my specific case/questions are as follow:

My data scheme is this:

```
{
  "aNumber" : 0.794180524700695,
  "clicks" : 11
}
```

My current validation rules are this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".validate": "newData.child('aNumber').isNumber()",
     ".read": true,
    ".write": true      
  }
}
```

This rule currently allows the write for "aNumber" if it is a number, but I would like to also validate for the field "clicks" to be a number.

I tried using the and operator (&&):

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".validate": "newData.child('aNumber').isNumber() && 
                 newData.child('clicks').isNumber()",
     ".read": true,
    ".write": true      
  }
}
```

But it fails when I only update one field:

```
{
 "aNumber": 2
}
```

How would I validate for this ? , what is a good way of validating multiple independent fields in general ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after some experimenting I found an answer to my own question:

My new rules look like this:

```
{
 "rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true,
  "aNumber": {
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
     },
   "clicks": {
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
     }                
 }
}
```

So instead of validating for a specific child node globally, the validation happens at the specific node level in the rules, this might be obvious to some, but it took me a bit to realize.

Comment: If I want to have it in a specific directory in the database, I'll just have to have another enclosing brackets?